# excel 2007 pivot on ssas

Tags: excel, ssas

I am new to this.

I built a pivot report in excel 2007 on SSAS. It connects to a cube on my local pc. Now I want to send this pivot report to other people to make them be able to view the pivot report and do some analysis by themselves (expanding year-month-day etc).

When my colleague tried he couldn't expand.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you,
Nian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your colleague needs to be able to access the cube in order to refresh it.  This means that your cube should be on a shared machine (like a server).  I would recommend putting the cube on a server and setup a database read-only user login and setup the Excel file to use that username/password.  You may be able to have your local machine be accessible, but I don't have experience with this and I would advise against it anyhow (your users wouldn't be able to refresh the cube if you don't have your computer on the network).

Also, even if you send them the file with data cached from the cube, only so much data gets cached.  When you expand items, it won't need to request the data from the cube (on your machine/server) if it has that particular data cached.  The same may happen when you create filters.

Comment: This is only for testing. I will put it on a server soon. I saw under Data->connections, there is a connection connecting to my local cube. Should I create a new connection using my server name (instead of 'local') and give the windows user name/password of my machine and send this .odc to my colleague? Unfortunately although he is my colleague we are in different locations so can't go to his place and see what happened. And I saw 'connection files on network' when I tried to create a connection. Is this something that supposed to do so that he can choose to use this connection? How to do it?

Comment: You can grant access to all domain users where you work so that anyone can access as long as they're logged into the domain (this would use Windows auth).  After that, yes, you would change the connection string from (local) to yourserver.yourdomain.net or something like that. Then save the workbook and you can give it to anyone and they can use it as long as they're logged into the domain where you work.